# Questions with watched tags no longer highlighted?

Tags: support, bug, tag-watching

Why are questions with my watched tags no longer highlighted when viewing the lists of questions (e.g. math stackexchange and mathoverflow)? I just noticed this today and also noticed the question list seems to be displayed in a slightly different format.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375481/please-revert-the-new-question-list-style-change

Comment: I think [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375479) specifically addresses your question.

Comment: Click on "Questions" on the left hand  (instead of "Home"), and you seem to get the old view, with suitable highlights. There is also a tag that says "watched" in the new standard view.

Comment: Looks like they've "fixed" this now?